# Как добавить изображение в товар UMI CMS?

Tags: php, umi

В кастомном обработчике ивента, произвожу запись из одного поля товара в другое, но изображение почему-то не записывается.
Код:

```
public function addImageToObject($e) {
      if($e->getMode() == "after") {
        $element = $e->getRef('element');
        if ($element->getMethod() != 'object') return false;
        $image1C = new umiImageFile($element->getValue('photo'));
        $element->setValue("photos", [$image1C]);
        $element->commit();
      }
}
```

Объект в `$image1C` есть:

```
    __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => umiImageFile
    [sImageType:umiImageFile:private] => JPEG
    [iImageWidth:umiImageFile:private] => 450
    [iImageHeight:umiImageFile:private] => 450
    [alt:umiImageFile:private] => 
    [filepath:protected] => ./images/cms/data/import_files/b0/sprut_mrs-5.jpeg
    [size:protected] => 60968
    [ext:protected] => jpeg
    [name:protected] => sprut_mrs-5.jpeg
    [dirname:protected] => ./images/cms/data/import_files/b0
    [modify_time:protected] => 1530800215
    [is_broken:protected] => 
    [order:protected] => 
    [id:protected] => 
    [ignoreSecurity:umiFile:private] => 
    [isReadable:umiFile:private] => 1
    [isWritable:umiFile:private] => 1
)
```

Comment: что-то вы вопрос задали и пропали

Comment: @ArthurShiriev у меня почему-то не работает, я перебрал все возможные вариации передачи параметра.

Comment: Можно попробовать распечатать $element->getValue('photo') и посмотреть, экземпляр ли это класса umiImageFile. 
Еще может стоит umi-cms обновить

Comment: @ArthurShiriev вы были правы, это я не разобрался с umi и пытался изменить не тот обьект. А нужно было всего лишь посмотреть док.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни к чему оборачивать $element->getValue('photo') в umiImageFile. Для полей с изображением и так возвращается экземпляр umiImageFile.

После такой модификации у меня сработало:

```
public function addImageToObject($e) {
      if($e->getMode() == "after") {
        $element = $e->getRef('element');
        if ($element->getMethod() != 'object') return false;
        $element->setValue("photos", [$element->getValue('photo')]);
        $element->commit();
      }
}
```